# Check if Autoshape exists

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I am trying to create a simple macro to delete some data including an Autoshape 
 - `Shapes("ACCESS")`, but I would like this macro to run only if Autoshape exists.

If it doesn't exist, the action would be just `Range("B2").Select`

Can anybody help please?

**My Code**

```
Sub DeleteRepWT()

ActiveSheet.Shapes("ACCESS").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 57#
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -85.5
Range("M4").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ACCESS").Select
Selection.Delete
Columns("K:AI").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("B2").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object type shape, in my code it's `Shp`, and try to set it to `Set Shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("ACCESS")`.

Add `On Error Resume Next` before trying to `Set` the shape object (so won't get a run-time error), and after trying to `Set` the shape, you can check `If Shp Is Nothing`, which means checking if you were able to `Set` the shape (if you weren't, it means there is no `Shapes("ACCESS")` in your worksheet).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRepWT()

Dim Shp As Shape

On Error Resume Next
Set Shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("ACCESS") ' try to set the object to "ACCESS"
On Error GoTo 0

If Shp Is Nothing Then ' if there is no Shapes("ACCESS")
    Range("B2").Select 
Else ' shape exists
    With Shp
        ' rest of your original code here ...

    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Spot on, Shai Rado - it worked well. Thank you very much for your help! Great answer!!!